# Does scale behave differently than position in after effects animation?

Tags: after-effects, animation, scale

In the GIF, if you notice, it looks like the scale is relatively fast at the beginning and gradually becomes slow at the end of loop. So I feel *speed* of zoom (scale) is not constant:

[image]

[image]

However, when I adjust the speed graph a bit like this, it makes the *speed* a bit constant. But that's just an hit and trial and not perfect. I don't understand why the default graph, which *seems* constant, behaved like that and altered graph, which *seems* increasing, makes it the way I want:

[image]

[image]

**But when we do any position (x or y) animation (without easy ease), for any object, the speed is constant without any doubt.**

So is it true scale behaves differently and scale *speed* isn't constant? If yes, is there any logical way to make the *speed* of scale constant (I mean making the zoom look like it's constant)?

Comment: This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but in general I stay away from the speed graph - the value graphs are much easier to understand imho...

Comment: I've never encountered this problem but I have a couple of ideas:

1. An illusion created by the 2 parallel lines getting really close to the edge as it feels like it jumps when you look at the edge of it and doesn't occur when the rotated square hits the edge with its corner.
2. The loop you made has cut a single frame from the end of it making it look like an imprecise motion, try manually creating a second loop before marking the end of the Work Area.

Comment: @Apeiron_Sound I think actually it's not a problem, it's how Scale property works.

Comment: I have tried this for a different design too. Faced same thing there also. So I don't think it has to do something with those rectangles.